# Aligning time series data sets with missing values for plotting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have three data sets with missing values, each consisting of a time column and one data column. The minimum time difference between two rows is 1 second (00:00:01):

```
Dataset 1:          Dataset 2:          Dataset 3:  
00:00:00    81                          00:00:00    70
00:00:01    81                      
00:00:02    81                      
00:00:03    81                          00:00:03    99
00:00:04    81                          00:00:04    100
00:00:05    80      00:00:05    80      00:00:05    101
00:00:06    80      00:00:06    100         
                    00:00:07    92      00:00:07    88
00:00:08    83      00:00:08    80      00:00:08    88
00:00:09    84      00:00:09    83      00:00:09    87
00:00:10    86                      
00:00:11    89                      
00:00:12    90                      
00:00:13    92                          00:00:13    92
00:00:14    94                          00:00:14    94
00:00:15    94      00:00:15    96      00:00:15    93
00:00:16    96      00:00:16    97          
00:00:17    98      00:00:17    100     00:00:17    99
00:00:18    100                         00:00:18    99
00:00:19    101                         00:00:19    101
00:00:20    103
```

For sake of visualization the table above shows empty fields for missing values. The real data is dense, e.g. looks like this:

```
Dataset 1:          Dataset 2:          Dataset 3:  
00:00:00    81      00:00:05    80      00:00:00    70
00:00:01    81      00:00:06    100     00:00:03    99
00:00:02    81      00:00:07    92      00:00:04    100
00:00:03    81      00:00:08    80      00:00:05    101
00:00:04    81      00:00:09    83      00:00:07    88
00:00:05    80      00:00:15    96      00:00:08    88
00:00:06    80      00:00:16    97      00:00:09    87
00:00:08    83      00:00:17    100     00:00:13    92
00:00:09    84                          00:00:14    94
00:00:10    86                          00:00:15    93
00:00:11    89                          00:00:17    99
00:00:12    90                          00:00:18    99
00:00:13    92                          00:00:19    101
00:00:14    94                      
00:00:15    94                      
00:00:16    96                      
00:00:17    98                      
00:00:18    100                     
00:00:19    101                     
00:00:20    103
```

Now I want to align the data so that it can be plotted this way:

[image: Combined]

and this way:

[image: Split]

My naive approach is this:

1. Find min/max times in each data set.
2. Create a table with a row for each time and three columns each having `n/a` as value.
3. Loop through each data set and assign values to the table.

Is there some Python function/library which performs these steps in an efficient manner? Or is there a better way to do this?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all DataFrames together with index by `time` column :

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df = pd.concat([x.set_index('time')['val'] for x in dfs], 
                axis=1, 
                keys=['a','b','c'],
                sort=True)
print (df)
              a      b      c
00:00:00   81.0    NaN   70.0
00:00:01   81.0    NaN    NaN
00:00:02   81.0    NaN    NaN
00:00:03   81.0    NaN   99.0
00:00:04   81.0    NaN  100.0
00:00:05   80.0   80.0  101.0
00:00:06   80.0  100.0    NaN
00:00:07    NaN   92.0   88.0
00:00:08   83.0   80.0   88.0
00:00:09   84.0   83.0   87.0
00:00:10   86.0    NaN    NaN
00:00:11   89.0    NaN    NaN
00:00:12   90.0    NaN    NaN
00:00:13   92.0    NaN   92.0
00:00:14   94.0    NaN   94.0
00:00:15   94.0   96.0   93.0
00:00:16   96.0   97.0    NaN
00:00:17   98.0  100.0   99.0
00:00:18  100.0    NaN   99.0
00:00:19  101.0    NaN  101.0
00:00:20  103.0    NaN    NaN
```

If some times missing in each DataFrame, add [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html), but is necessary `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.asfreq('S')
df.index = df.index.time
print (df)
              a      b      c
00:00:00   81.0    NaN   70.0
00:00:01   81.0    NaN    NaN
00:00:02   81.0    NaN    NaN
00:00:03   81.0    NaN   99.0
00:00:04   81.0    NaN  100.0
00:00:05   80.0   80.0  101.0
00:00:06   80.0  100.0    NaN
00:00:07    NaN   92.0   88.0
00:00:08   83.0   80.0   88.0
00:00:09   84.0   83.0   87.0
00:00:10   86.0    NaN    NaN
00:00:11   89.0    NaN    NaN
00:00:12   90.0    NaN    NaN
00:00:13   92.0    NaN   92.0
00:00:14   94.0    NaN   94.0
00:00:15   94.0   96.0   93.0
00:00:16   96.0   97.0    NaN
00:00:17   98.0  100.0   99.0
00:00:18  100.0    NaN   99.0
00:00:19  101.0    NaN  101.0
00:00:20  103.0    NaN    NaN
```

Last for ploting use [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.plot()
```

And for separate each plot:

```
df.plot(subplots=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I just had to add some interpolation ``df = df.interpolate(method ='linear') ``.